# GPS/GNSS standard active antenna voltage and current draw

Tags: antenna, gps, gnss

I'm designing a GNSS receiver that I'd like to be compatible with a variety of different active antennas. What antenna voltages are possible, and is there any (unofficial) standardization of this? I've seen 3.3 V, 5 V, and 12 V. Anything else?

Is there any standard range for current draw? It seems like 30-50 mA is fairly typical. Is that an accurate assessment?

Uncommon outliers would be useful to know about too.

Comment: Your receiver needs to provide the needed voltage and current to the active antenna?

Comment: Nope, not necessarily. But having the antenna power go through the receiver PCB makes it easier for the receiver to provide some features, like being able to detect if an antenna is present or not. Currently, the design permits using 3.3V or 5V from the receiver (which are available anyway), or bypassing that entirely and providing the supply externally with a separate bias-t.